# Windows service Not able to access shared location

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, shared

I have a windows service running with a local account let say **"servername\User1"**.
when i log in with this user on server I am able to open a shared location let say **"\SharedServer\Dir1"**.
but when service run it is not able to acces the same location and get error

> "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Answer (score 0):

Try running the service in the user account where it works properly:

http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService

Comment: servername\User1 is the account which can access shared location. and it is not able to access same location when service is configured to run with this logon.

Comment: Do you have to enter a password when you access that share for the first time after you login to that account?